# Getting Messages sent to my sister's iPhone on my MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, messages

My sister and I both have iPhones and whenever someone texts her, I get those messages sent to my MacBook Air. It's really annoying and I haven't been able to figure out how to fix it!

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a bug, probably her iPhone and your MacBook are connected with the same Apple ID account. Just log out from her Apple ID in "System Preferences > Internet Accounts" and from "System Preferences > Users & Groups > Your Mac Account > Advanced settings > Change Apple ID".